# Where do I define my variables?

Tags: java, variables

So in my little Java program I had declared all my variables in the main method, but I wanted to be able to modify them from anywhere inside the class, so I declared them in the class body instead. Now I am not able to modify them inside the main method anymore. Is the solution for this to declare the variables static? If I were to do so would I still be able to change those variables from inside the main method?

```
public class MainGUI
{
  int num1= 1366, num2= 528, num3= 482, sum; // declare these static?

  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    sum = num1 + num2+ num3; //compiler tells me "non-static varable cannot be refrenced from a static context"
  }
}
```

Comment: You define variables inside of classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to create an **instance of your class** in order to **access non static variables** from your **static methods** in java.

```
public class MainGUI
{
  int num1= 1366, num2= 528, num3= 482, sum; // declare these static?

  public static void main(String args[])
  {
MainGui m = new MainGUI();
    sum = m.num1 + m.num2+ m.num3; 
  }
}
```

or make your **instance variables static** so that you can  access them directly without any instance from your static methods .

```
  public class MainGUI
    {
      static int num1= 1366, num2= 528, num3= 482, sum; // declare these static?

      public static void main(String args[])
      {
        sum = num1 + num2+ num3; 
      }
    }
```

though, by convention static variables from static methods should be accessed with **classname.variablename**

```
      sum =  MainGUI.num1 + MainGUI.num2 + MainGUI.num3;
```

please refer to this link about better understanding of [different types of variable access](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

Comment: @lightice11 you are welcome. and please read about variable access as others mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainGUI
{
  static int num1= 1366;
..
..

  public static void main(String args[])
  {
   MainGUI.sum = MainGUI.num1 + MainGUI.num2+ MainGUI.num3; 
  }
}
```

Comment: no need calling the class name, inside the class itself